# How to proper align three TextViews horizontally with ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to align three TextViews horizontally (as the title may suggest), but even after chaining they together and using `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` they're still being pushed out of the screen, strangely only by the left side when the middle or the last one grows large. Notice that I'm setting the `android:maxLines="1"` and `android:ellipsize="end"` and aligning they at the start of the screen, not sure if it matters though.

I also tried to limit their sizes, but on the case where there are two small texts and a very large one the large one will be ellipsized even when the layout still have some space left.

Sample layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="22dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/greenTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/blueTextView"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blueTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/greenTextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/orangetextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/greenTextView"
            tools:text="Another TextView " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orangetextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/blueTextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/blueTextView"
            tools:text="Another TextView" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

### These are some cases using the sample layout

None of the TextViews are ellipsizing:

[image: First case]

The first TextView is ellipsizing:

[image: Second case]

The last TextView don't ellipsize and pushes the other ones out of the screen:

[image: Third case]

---

### These are some possible solutions that aren't covering all of the cases

Using `android:maxWidth="90dp"` to prevent the TextView to grow, but also limiting the text unnecessarily:

[image: Fourth case]

Using `android:layout_width="0dp"` to enable "match_constraint" is not a optimal solution as well, since the layout will reserve a third of the display width for each TextView, even if the text is smaller than that:

[image: Fifth case]

Comment: Maybe it's not possible to achieve the effect you want with ConstraintLayout. If it works with Flexbox, then you could go with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Flexbox

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:alignContent="flex_start"
        app:alignItems="flex_start"
        app:flexWrap="nowrap"
        app:dividerDrawable="@drawable/ic_divider"
        app:showDivider="middle">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_minWidth="50dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="Text View"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_minWidth="50dp"
            android:text="Another TextView"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_minWidth="50dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="Another TextView"/>

</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

Output of this layout:

[image: Short text]

[image: Equalized text size]

[image: Long text]

Answer (score 0):

You can use linear layout instead. When the text grows it will ellipsized end with ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="22dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/greenTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        tools:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/blueTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        tools:text="Another TextView " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orangetextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        tools:text="Another TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: `app:layout_constraint***` not needed for LinearLayout

Comment: Sorry mistakenly putted that thing. :)

Comment: Thx for your answer, but that is limiting the size of the TextViews to be a third of the total width of the screen, e.g.: if the first text was small the layout will still reserve the same space unnecessarily.

Comment: In that case you can use `FlexboxLayout` which will automatically shift the next `TextView` to the new line when the first one reaches to the right. If you want I can edit the above answer with `FlexboxLayout`.

Comment: The idea is to ellipsize the text and keep all three of them in one line, I tried with flexbox as well but without success, if you know how to do that it would be a great help. Also just for curiosity purposes I wish to know if it's possible to do that using only ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Then there is only one option which is Linear layout with layout_weight otherwise you will see text going off the screen.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this one (just make sure to replace androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout with  android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="22dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/greenTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/blueTextView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="First Very Long Text 123456789" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/blueTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/greenTextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/orangetextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/greenTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Second Very Long Text 123456789" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orangetextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/blueTextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/blueTextView"
        tools:text="Third Very Long Text 123456789" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Ellipsize will work as expected.

[image]

Comment: Thx for your answer, but this reserves a third of the width for each TextView, similar to using weights on a linear layout, so if the first text is small it will reserve an additional space that could be used to display more text on the other two.